# Why is program returning Unrecognised Callback while making Call through Soap Service

Tags: spring-boot, soap-client, soapfault

I have a new spring boot application that is attempting to make a soap call by extending Springs WebServiceGatewaySupport class, but receive "Unrecognised Callback" error.

I've tried modifying my getWebService method to use different varieties of getWebServiceTemplate implementations but continue to receive the error.

```
public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Object callWebService(String url, Object request) {
        setInterceptor();
        setMarshallerAndUnmarshaller();


    //      return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);

        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                url, request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                        logger.info(message);

                    }
                });
    }

    public void setInterceptor() {
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        interceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken Timestamp");
        interceptor.setSecurementUsername("username");
        interceptor.setSecurementPassword("password");
        interceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenNonce(true);
        this.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{interceptor});
    }

    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.widget.api.job");
        return marshaller;
    }

    public void setMarshallerAndUnmarshaller() {
        this.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        this.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
    }
}
```

Here's a few lines from the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Unrecognised Callback; nested exception is: 
javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException: Unrecognised Callback
at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
at com.test.service.SOAPConnector.callWebService(SOAPConnector.java:23)
at com.test.service.ClientImpl.springCall(ClientImpl.java:77)
at com.test.service.ClientImpl.previewDocument(ClientImpl.java:102)
at com.test.processor.ProcessorImpl.processEvent(ProcessorImpl.java:61)
at com.test.service.ServiceImpl.processMessage(ServiceImpl.java:33)
at com.test.controller.Endpoint.test(Endpoint.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134)
at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:291)
at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:55)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:236)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How does your url look like?

Comment: URL works when sending request through SoapUI

Comment: Do you have some more stacktrace? Any other errors or warnings?

Comment: Full stacktrace has been added

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a data related issue.  For some reason the sever was returning back this generic message.  Seems like it was doing some sort of validation or something, not absolutely sure.  But I updated some of the info being passed and it's working now.